# How to AJAX POST file contents together with other data to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, filereader

I want to create a form where the user adds some information (text in inputs, selects, etc.) and uploads a file. For example if I have a Product entity that looks like this

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProductImage { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do a POST via AJAX to a Web API action that looks like this

```
public void Post(Product product)
```

I want the name string and the bytes to be sent together. I don't want to upload the file in advance.

What should I do on the client to send the data preferably as JSON. One thing that seems easy is make ProductImage a string and send base64 encoded data which is easy to read with the FileReader API but is this the correct way? It seems cleaner to have the data map to a byte array which it actually is.

Comment: Great example here: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/uploading-files-asynchronously-using-asp.net-web-api.htm

Comment: @MatthewatCriticalCognition this example only seems to upload a file, not other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up base64 encoding the file and sending it as part of the JSON then parsing it on the server into a byte array. One should be careful when allowing upload of large files but for small files it seems to be fine.